# I think I found a new hobby

Tags: riddle, visual

Can you guess the word from the following images?

[image: Cars on a track]

[image: Depiction of deadly conflict]

[image: Insect on a leaf]

[image: Stark on a Pike]

[image: Blue Ocean]

[image: Binary Button]

[image: Foot Wear]

[image: Wild Wolves]

[image: Stack of outdoor wear]

Comment: Uh... I'd answer but my throats a little dry...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Word is:

> Horse

Title:

> Hobby Horse

1)

> Horse Race

2)

> War Horse

3)

> Horsefly

4)

> Horsehead

5)

> Seahorse

6)

> Horsepower

7)

> Horseshoe

8)

> Pack Horse

9)

> Hold Horses

Comment: Seahorse could also be read as *horsea* as a reference ;) and last one should be *hold your horses*

Comment: Correct, although "Hold Horses" isn't exactly what I was going for.

Comment: 8 is pack horse

Comment: That's the one :)

Comment: @Raeles What were you going for instead of Hold (your) Horses?

Comment: I think 9 is clothes horse, a rack for drying clothes on.

Comment: @MOehm That's correct :)